# Issue when Table with Inputs is inside of a Form

Tags: html, angular, forms

I'm building an Angular application with `PrimeNG`. I have a form that contains a p-table (list of products) with inputs (quantity and price), when I select the first product from a dialog and enter the inputs (quantity and price), then select a second product, I lose the first quantity and price that enter for the first product.

This issue only happened when putting the table with inputs inside of the form.
Is there a right way to resolve this? My code is below.

**HTML:**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="valider(form)">

  <p-table [value]="object.produits" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Code Produit</th>
        <th>Quantité</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-produit>
      <tr [pSelectableRow]="produit">
        <td>{{produit.codeProduit}}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" size="10" pInputText name="quantite" [readonly]="action=='show'" pKeyFilter="num" [ngModel]="produit.quantite" (ngModelChange)="produit.quantite = $event;">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" size="10" pInputText name="prixUnitaire" [readonly]="action=='show'" pKeyFilter="num" [ngModel]="produit.prixUnitaire"(ngModelChange)="produit.prixUnitaire = $event;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
      <button type="button" (click)="showDialogProduit()" pButton label="Ajouter Produit"></button>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>


</form>



<p-dialog header="Liste des produits" [(visible)]="dialogProduit" >
  <p-table #dt_produits [value]="produits" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="operationCommodities.produits" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Désignation</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-produit>
      <tr [pSelectableRow]="produit">
        <td>{{produit.codeProduit}}</td>
        <td>{{produit.designation}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
      <button pButton type="button" label="Terminer" (click)="closeDialogProduit()"></button>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</p-dialog>
```

**TS:**

```
showDialogProduit() {
this.dialogProduit = true;
}

closeDialogProduit() {
this.dialogProduit = false;
}
```

**Stackblitz Demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-a7bdgm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-civjwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: hi, i've made an update in https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-a7bdgm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that input fields don't have a unique name which messes up how `ngModel` directive works. When I updated the code as follows, it was fixed. Note that the `[name]` attributes of both input fields are dynamic values based on `produit.codeProduit`

```
<tr [pSelectableRow]="produit">
  <td>{{produit.codeProduit}} </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" size="10" pInputText [name]="'quantite_' + produit.codeProduit" [readonly]="action=='show'" pKeyFilter="num" [ngModel]="produit.quantite" (ngModelChange)="produit.quantite = $event;">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" size="10" pInputText [name]="'prixUnitaire_' + produit.codeProduit"  [readonly]="action=='show'" pKeyFilter="num" [ngModel]="produit.prixUnitaire"(ngModelChange)="produit.prixUnitaire = $event;">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Please check [Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-4dwuk2) with updated code.

As an aside, I recommend you change your implementation to use [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of `ngModel`;